# Adicionar métodos em Date usando o typescript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, typescript

Estou tentando criar um método formate a data. Algo como

```
var minhaData = new Date();
console.log(minhaData.format('[d]/[m]/[Y]'));
```

eu busquei na internet e consegui desenvolver este trecho:

```
interface Date{
    format(formato:string):string;
}

Date.prototype.format = (formato:string) =>{
    var dataHora = this;
    var hora     = dataHora.getHours();

    formato = formato.replace("[h]",hora);
    return formato;
}
```

porém o resultado no console é `undefined`.
Gostaria que retornasse a hora atual.

Comment: Você quer mesmo alterar o protótipo de Date? Acredito que o meio mais "Typescript" de fazer isso seria extender a classe Date.

Answer (score 1):

Bem olhando assim seu conceito esta correto, você deve estender a "classe Date" *(já que JS não usa de fato classes pra heranças)* e adicionar seu método, no caso "format", mas acredito que o erro esta sendo na tipagem, pois o JavaScript é fracamente tipado, então você não precisa definir *(alias ele nem aceita manipulação de tipos apenas conversões)* e os tipos ele meio que entende sozinho.

Então reformulando seu código ele ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<script>
// Adiciona um método a classe "Date" e cria uma função anonima
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
 // Dias (g = Global ~ trocar todas ocorrencias)
 var newFormat = format.replace(/\[d]/g, this.getDate()); // Troca o Dia
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[m]/g, (this.getMonth() + 1)); // Troca o Mês
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[Y]/g, this.getFullYear()); // Troca o ano Completo
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[y]/g, this.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 4)); // Troca o ano Simples

 // Horas (g = Global ~ trocar todas ocorrencias)
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[H]/g, this.getHours()); // Troca a Hora formato 24h
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[h]/g, (this.getHours() % 12 || 12)); // Troca a Hora formato 12h
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[i]/g, this.getMinutes()); // Troca os Minutos
 newFormat = newFormat.replace(/\[s]/g, this.getSeconds()); // Troca os Segundos

 // Retorna
 return newFormat;
};

// Teste
var agora = new Date();
console.log(agora.format("[d]/[m]/[y] - [h]:[i]:[s]"));
console.log(agora.format("[d]/[m]/[Y] - [H]:[i]:[s]"));
console.log(agora.format("[d]/[m]/[Y] - [H]:[i]:[s] && [d]/[m]/[Y] - [H]:[i]:[s]")); 
</script>
```

Testando no IE 11, Chorme 48+ e FireFox 43+.

Comment: preciso fazer isso utitlizando o typescript, com JS puro eu consigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo como simplesmente isso:

```
class DateFormat  {

    private data:Date;
    private dateFormatted:string;
    private masc:string = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    private dia:any;
    private mes:any;
    private ano:any;
    private ano_res:any;
    private hora:any;
    private minuto:any;
    private segundo:any;

    constructor(objData:Date, mascView?:string) {
        this.data    = objData;
        this.dia     = (this.data.getDate() < 10) ? '0'+this.data.getDate() : this.data.getDate();
        this.mes     = ((this.data.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0'+(this.data.getMonth() + 1) : this.data.getMonth() + 1;
        this.ano     = this.data.getFullYear();
        this.ano_res = [this.data.getFullYear().toString().split('')[2],this.data.getFullYear().toString().split('')[3]].join('');
        this.hora    = (this.data.getHours() < 10) ? '0'+this.data.getHours() : this.data.getHours();
        this.minuto  = (this.data.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0'+this.data.getMinutes() : this.data.getMinutes();
        this.segundo = (this.data.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0'+this.data.getSeconds() : this.data.getSeconds();
        let format = (mascView) ? mascView : this.masc;
            format = format.replace(/d/, this.dia)
            .replace(/m/, this.mes)
            .replace(/Y/, this.ano)
            .replace(/y/, this.ano_res)
            .replace(/H/, this.hora)
            .replace(/i/, this.minuto)
            .replace(/s/, this.segundo);
        this.dateFormatted = format;
    }

    public getDateFormatted() {

        return this.dateFormatted;
    }

}

var data = new DateFormat(new Date(),'d/m/Y H:i:s');
console.log(data.getDateFormatted());
```